# Denied Access of Port 443 (https://) on another Computer on Network, using WampServer

Tags: apache, wampserver

Using **Apache2.4.33**, I was able to allow access to another computer on the network on **port 80**, however I can't seem to work out how to do the same with **port 443** for a secure connection.

My httpd-vhosts.conf file: (if relevant)

```
    # Virtual Hosts
    #
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      ServerAlias localhost
      DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
      <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

**Port 443** works perfectly on the computer I am hosting it on.

Comment: See [WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) or [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Answer (score 0):

**Worked Out the Issue by my self in the End:**

Add these Lines of Code:

```
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
   #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/yoursite/">
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Where I have added the # in "httpd-ssl.conf" which is stored in "\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.x.xx\conf\extra\":

```
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
# <--This Hashtag!!!
```

This fixes the **Port 443** Denied Issue.